# Pass activity result into a react native module

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to do some speech to text recognition using react native. I wrote a react module to start a recognizer intent

```
public class SpeechToTextModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

...

  @ReactMethod
  public void startListening(Callback errorCallback, Callback successCallback) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);

    if(getCurrentActivity() != null){
        getReactApplicationContext().startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE, null);
    } else {
        errorCallback.invoke(new NullPointerException("Activity is null"));
    }
}

  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    // control must come here
  }
```

The mainactivity looks like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  ...

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // how do i invoke the module function?
  }
}
```

MainActivity receives the result from the voice intent, but I cant figure out how I can pass it over to the module.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a way to [register as Activity event listener](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android#getting-activity-result-from-startactivityforresult).

Add this to your Native Module:

```
public class SpeechToTextModule 
  extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule 
  implements ActivityEventListener {

  public SpeechToTextModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
    reactContext.addActivityEventListener(this); //Register this native module as Activity result listener 
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Here is your Activity result :)
  }

  @Override
  public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution didn't work for me. I had to create an ActivityEventListener.

```
public class SpeechToTextModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule  {
    private static ReactApplicationContext reactContext = null;
    private Callback callback;

    private final ActivityEventListener mActivityEventListener = new BaseActivityEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            System.out.println("Called this method" + resultCode + "request code" + requestCode);
            if (requestCode == 2) {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    String transactionId = data.getStringExtra("transactionId");
                    String amount = data.getStringExtra("amount");
                    String status = data.getStringExtra("status");
                    WritableMap map = Arguments.createMap();
                    map.putString("transactionId", transactionId);
                    map.putString("amount", amount);
                    map.putString("status", status);
                    callback.invoke(map);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public SslCommerzBridgeModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
        // Pass in the context to the constructor and save it so you can emit events
        // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#the-toast-module
        super(context);
        context.addActivityEventListener(mActivityEventListener);
        reactContext = context;
    }
}`

@ReactMethod
    public void testMethod(String sslCommerzParams, Callback callback) {
        Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();
        Intent intent = new Intent(reactContext, PaymentActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("SSL", sslCommerzParams);
        this.callback = callback;
        reactContext.startActivityForResult(intent, 2, null);
    }
```

I wrote this to make it work for me.

Comment: where's the startActivityForResult implementation?

Comment: when SslCommerzBridgeModule() call?

Comment: Can you write code of PaymentActivity where you must have resulted callback?

Answer (score 0):

I actually made it work with the below method in react-native v0.64:

in your MainActivity:

```java
...
private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;
...
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    mReactInstanceManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

in your Module:

```java
public class MyModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements ActivityEventListener {
    static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;

    final ReactApplicationContext reactContext;
    Promise promise;

    public GeneralIntentModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        this.reactContext = reactContext;
        this.reactContext.addActivityEventListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "MyModule ";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void captureVideo(Promise promise) {
        this.promise = promise;
        Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(this.reactContext.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            this.reactContext.startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE, null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        this.promise.resolve(data.getDataString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If any one using kotlin with react-native module with Promise, plesae refer below code,

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.util.Log
import com.facebook.react.bridge.*
import com.onboardinglib.HostActivity

class ConsistyOnboarding (reactContext: ReactApplicationContext) :
  ReactContextBaseJavaModule(reactContext) {

  private val CODE = 999
  private var promise: Promise? = null
  private val reContext: ReactApplicationContext? = reactContext

  fun dumpIntent(intent: Intent) {
    LogPrint("Bundle data", "Dumping intent start")

    val bundleData = intent.extras
    if (bundleData != null) {
      for (key in bundleData.keySet()) {
        LogPrint(
          "Bundle data-->",
          key + " : " + if (bundleData[key] != null) bundleData[key] else "NULL"
        )
      }
    }
  }

  override fun getName(): String {
    return "ConsistyOnboarding"
  }

  private val mActivityEventListener: ActivityEventListener =
    object : BaseActivityEventListener() {
      override fun onActivityResult(
        activity: Activity,
        requestCode: Int,
        resultCode: Int,
        data: Intent
      ) {
        LogPrint("mActivityEventListener", "Started")

        if (data == null) {
          resolve("01", "No action taken", "0")
          return
        }

        dumpIntent(data)

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
          try {
            val status = data.getBooleanExtra("status", false)
            val response = data.getIntExtra("response", 0)
            val message = data.getStringExtra("message")
            resolve(status.toString(), response.toString(), message.toString())
            return
          } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            resolve("01", "Exception occurred in on-boarding " + e.message, "0")
          }
        }
        resolve("01", "No action taken", "0")
      }
    }


  init {
    reContext?.addActivityEventListener(mActivityEventListener)
  }


  @ReactMethod
  fun Onboarding(
    partnerId: String, partnerKey: String  prm: Promise
  ) {

    promise = prm
    val currentActivity = currentActivity
    val intent = Intent(currentActivity, HostActivity::class.java)

    intent.putExtra("pId", partnerId) 
    intent.putExtra("ApiKey", partnerKey) 
    
    try {
      currentActivity?.startActivityForResult(intent, CODE)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      e.printStackTrace()
      resolve("01", "No action taken", "0")
    }
  }

  private fun resolve(
    statusCode: String,
    response: String,
    message: String
  ) {
    if (promise == null) {
      return
    }

    val map = Arguments.createMap()

    map.putString("statusCode", statusCode)
    map.putString("response", response)
    map.putString("message", message)

    promise!!.resolve(map)
    promise = null
  }

  private fun LogPrint(key: String?, value: String?) {
    if (key == null || value == null) {
      return
    }
    Log.i(key, value)
  }
}
```

Here main part is

```
init {
    reContext?.addActivityEventListener(mActivityEventListener)
  }
```